# How to add multiple models to a single listview?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

i need to be able to display information from multiple models in a single listview but haven't a clue how to go about doing this any help would be very helpful...

here is my code for me views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from . models import Post, Task
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator



@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class HomeView(ListView):
    template_name = 'home.html'
    model = Post



@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class Task(ListView):
    model = Task
    template_name = 'tasks.html'
```

here is my code for me models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    auther = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' | ' + str(self.auther)


class Task(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    urgency = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self,):
        return str(self.user.username) + ' | ' + 'Tasks'
```

here is my html:

```
        {% for task in object_list %}
                                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-transparent border border-secondary">
                                                    <h class="mb-1">{{task.title}}</h>
                                                    <p class="mb-1">{{task.description}}</p>
                                                    <a class="mb-1">{{task.urgency}}</a>
                                                </a>
                                            {% endfor %}
```

```
                {% for post in object_list %}
                    <span>
                        <div class="card text-secondary-emphasis border border-secondary mb-4" style="background-color: #0d1117;">
                          <div class="card-header border border-secondary">{{post.type}}</div>
                          <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title"style="color: #c0c0c0;">{{post.title}}</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">{{post.description}}</p>
                                <a href="{{post.link}}" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Read More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </span>
            {% endfor %}
```

if you need any more info on what im trying to achieve or need to see any other code snippets just let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, TemplateView could be more suitable for you. If you aren`t going to use pagination, ListView is not really what you need.
Here is how your code could look:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.extra_context = {
            "posts": Post.objects.all(),
            "tasks": Task.objects.all(),
        }
        return self.render_to_response(self.extra_context)
```

And, therefore, you will have to change tags in your templates and replace object_list to posts and tasks respectfully. It should look like this:

```
{% for post in posts %}
{% for task in tasks %}
```

Hope it will help you!